# How to get the duplicate row count in postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

In the table data is like this

```
st_no     st_name       directions            others

1210      6th street                        Northwest
1210      8th ST          NW                   NULL
```

Need output like (1210,1210) (6th street ,8th st) Northwest

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated. And, in case it comes into play, I'm using a Postgresql DB.

Comment: (1) What does the title have to do with the expected output?  (2) What are the parentheses supposed to mean in the expected output?

Comment: Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated. And, in case it comes into play, I'm using a Postgresql DB.

Comment: We can't provide any help unless you ask a clear question.

Comment: Already table has like that, in that how many times 1210 has came? 2 times so st_N0_hits(1210,1210) and st_name_hits(6thstreet ,8thst) and directions_hits (value of the directions) like this output needed

Comment: @Prince . . . `(1210, 1210)` is not a *count*.  A count would be a number like `1` or `2`.  That is why we don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: `select st_no,count(st_no) from yourTable group by st_no`

Comment: @Prince How can you say that its a duplicate per your example ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
select string_agg(st_no,',') as st_no,
string_agg(st_name,',') as st_name,
string_agg(directions,',') as directions,
string_agg(others,',') as others from table1 group by st_no
```

Comment: Thanking you very much Satish sir